# variable value becomes undefined in NodeJS ExpressJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am working with NodeJS using ExpressJS framework in a mysql backend. I am running a query inside a for loop and my loop and work afterwards depends on the return value of the query. I am not very good with mysql query so I am running it through a for loop. 
The problem is, due asynchronous [I guess!], the for loop ends long before the query result comes out.

Here is my code:

```
function search_people_step2(user_id, search_criteria, user_friend)
{
  var first_name_friends = [];
  var last_name_friends = [];


  for(var i = 0; i < user_friend.length; i++)
  {
    con.query("SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user WHERE userid = ?", user_friend[i],function(err, rows)
   {
     if(err)
     {
       //error;
     }
     else
     {
       if(rows.length == 0)
       { 
         //nothing gets returned
       }
       else {
         console.log(rows);
         first_name_friends[i] = rows[0].first_name;
         last_name_friends[i] = rows[0].second_name;
       }
 }
 });
}
```

Now,I can get the value (using console.log) inside the query statement, however, on the outside, the value becomes empty (undefined) since the rest of the code has already been computed.

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't except if there is a synchronous method to execute query.

Comment: How can I write a synchronous method in JS?

Comment: You can't, as it depends on the sql implementation. You could use promises if you really want to return somthing...

Comment: @n00dl3, I did not understand. can you please elaborate? sorry. I have poor knowledge on sql statements...

Comment: I'm currently writing on my mobile phone. I'll help you more when i get home.

Comment: @DineshAgrawal, First_name_friends and last_name_friends;

Comment: @n00dl3, thanks.. really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I find weird in your code is that you are not using an `IN` statement in your SQL query (not directly related to your problem though) which means you are making as many requests as there are entries in `user_friend`. The problem is that the SQL library is implemented asynchronously and you cannot avoid it. BUT you can handle it elegantly with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which are ES6 features:
(I didn't test the code but I think it should work)

```
function search_people_step2(user_id, search_criteria, user_friend)
{
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var first_name_friends = [];
    var last_name_friends = [];
    var placeHolders=user_friend.map(()=>"?").join(",");
    con.query("SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user WHERE userid IN ("+placeHolders+")",user_friend,(err,rows)=>{
      if(err)
        reject(err);
      else{
        rows.forEach(row=>{
          first_name_friends.push(row.first_name);
          last_name_friends.push(row.second_name);
        });
        resolve({first_name_friends,last_name_friends});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And call your function like this :

```
search_people_step2(id,crit,friends).then(result=>{
  //handle result asynchronously as there is no choice
  console.log(result.first_name_friends);
  console.log(result.last_name_friends);
}).catch(err=>{
  //handle error
});
```

Comment: my NodeJS is throwing an error when I am calling search function in the result=> ( for the > sign).....

Comment: what is the exact error, please ? and what is your nodejs version ?

Comment: its okay. I used a counter to handle the request for this purpose (to make it async) and moved on. However, I may need to implement this patter in later!

Answer (score 1):

```
simplest solution is 

function search_people_step2(user_id, search_criteria, user_friend)
    {
      var first_name_friends = [];
      var last_name_friends = [];


      for(var i = 0; i < user_friend.length; i++)
      {
        con.query("SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user WHERE userid = ?", user_friend[i],function(err, rows)
       {
         if(err)
         {
           //error;
         }
         else
         {
           if(rows.length == 0)
           { 
             //nothing gets returned
           }
           else {
             console.log(rows);
             first_name_friends[i] = rows[0].first_name;
             last_name_friends[i] = rows[0].second_name;
           }
          if(i==user_friend.length-1){
           //do your work here which you want to perform in end
          }
     }
     });
    }
```

or use async library

```
var async = require('async');
var first_name_friends = [];
var last_name_friends = [];

async.series([function(cb){
function search_people_step2(user_id, search_criteria, user_friend)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < user_friend.length; i++)
  {
    con.query("SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user WHERE userid = ?", user_friend[i],function(err, rows)
   {
     if(err)
     {
       //error;
     }
     else
     {
       if(rows.length == 0)
       { 
         //nothing gets returned
       }
       else {
         console.log(rows);
         first_name_friends[i] = rows[0].first_name;
         last_name_friends[i] = rows[0].second_name;
       }
if(i==user_friend.length-1){
       cb()
      }
 }
 });
}
},function(cb){
//do your work here 
}],function(err){})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your problem is the asynchronous nature of the mysql call. You have to provide a callback to your `search_people_step2` function.
You may change it like this:

```
search_people_step2(user_id, search_criteria, user_friend, callback)
```

In your function body you may use a library called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle all the callbacks properly. Here is an example for the usage:

```
async.eachSeries(user_friend, function(item, eachCb){
    con.query("SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user WHERE userid = ?", 
       user_friend[i],function(err, rows) {
       if(err) {
         eachCb('error');
       }
       else {
         if(rows.length == 0){ 
           //nothing gets returned
           eachCb(null);
         }
         else {
           console.log(rows);
           first_name_friends.push(rows[0].first_name);
           last_name_friends.push(rows[0].second_name);
           eachCb(null);
        }
      }
   }, callback);
});
```

This calls each query in order on every item of the array and calls the inner callback if finished. When all items are processed or an error occured the outer callback is called. See the async library for further documentation.

Comment: what can be the call back function? what did u mean by eachCB? 
In each callback, do I call back to my own function search_result_.... ?

Comment: "callback" is the function handed over from the call to search_people... . You may replace the third argument to the async.eachSeries by an anonymous function function(err) { // do something after everything is done } and then call the callback from the search_people....; The eachCb is the callback for every item. See the linked documentation for further details.